# Backbone Jquery Click huge delay on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, backbone.js, web

In a BackBone project for a specific page all click events are delayed for a period of 10 seconds (between touchstart and click) for iOS 8 and for 3 seconds between touchstart and touchend.

For iOS 9 the delays are 0.5 seconds and 0.1 for the same.
i'm aware of the 300 ms delay on mobile devices, but where to start debugging for this delay of 10 seconds ? Other solutions that fire click event on touchend don't work for me, i want to replace click with touchstart for that page.

Tested on safari.

Comment: FYI: Backbone is just a framework. It doesn't deal with DOM events directly.

Comment: @hindmost Agreed. But it has a different way on how we declare our events, it has to be in the Backbone.View.extend section.

Comment: It is just a way to declare event handlers. It doesn't affect on events implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the problem was fixed when i removed the following line from my css ( i had to reverse on my git to find this )

```
 *:focus, *:visited, *:active, *:link {outline:0;}
```

Any feedback on why this could have caused the problem is welcome.